# Python - web scraping Pubmed abstract - want to create 2 line breaks between sections (separated by all caps and ":")

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, line-breaks, pubmed

I want to web scrape abstracts from pubmed.gov and create line breaks/a paragraph between each section so it's not all crunched together.  The sections will typically be in all caps followed by a colon.  Example: INTRODUCTION: or SUMMARY: or METHODS.

I want to parse each section and create 2 line breaks between each section.

What I'm getting now: INTRODUCTION: blah blah blah. METHODS: We conducted an experiment to do X. CONCLUSION: This is an awesome experiment.

Desired output:

INTRODUCTION: blah blah blah.

METHODS: We conducted an experiment to do X.

CONCLUSION: This is an awesome experiment.

IMPORTANT NOTE: The headings will not always be the same, but will always be all caps followed by a double colon. So I guess I need to figure out how to use regex to look for a word with call caps and a double colon and create 2 line breaks.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import datetime
import csv
import time

listofa_urls = ['https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30470520', 
'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31063262','https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31067303']

for l in listofa_urls:
    response = requests.get(l)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    x = soup.find(class_='abstr').get_text()
    #print(x.encode("utf-8"))
    x = re.sub(r"\babstract(.*?)", r"\1", x, flags=re.I)

    print(x.encode("utf-8"))
    print()
```

Comment: how about `[A-Z]+:`

Comment: Just so I'm clear, can you show me in my code? Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Improved upon your code for this 3 url only.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

listofa_urls = ['https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30470520',
'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31063262','https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31067303']

for l in listofa_urls:
    response = requests.get(l)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    div_ = soup.find(class_='abstr').find('div')
    if div_.find('h4'):
        h4_ = div_.find_all('h4')
        p_ = div_.find_all('p')
    else:
        h4_ = soup.find(class_='abstr').find_all('h3')
        p_ = soup.find(class_='abstr').find_all('p')

    mp = list(map(lambda x, y: [x.get_text(),y.get_text()], h4_, p_))

    print(mp)
    print()
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  However, I'm still not getting line breaks, it's still treating it like a list, unfortunately without line breaks.  I want to export this to an Excel file or CSV if that helps.  Here's an excerpt if this helps: [['Abstract', 'Cirrhosis is morbid and increasingly prevalent - yet the U.S. healthcare system lacks enough physicians and specialists to adequately manage patients with cirrhosis.

Comment: pandas can take care of export to excel as well. `writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_with_rich_strings.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')` and then in loop  `df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)` `writer.save()`